# Not getting power to a new C Wire

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I am trying to finish installation of a new nest thermostat and ran into the dreaded “no C wire” issue. After reviewing several posts here, I felt pretty confident that with my new-ish furnace I could just attach one of my spare wires to the C terminal and call it good. But I’m having issues getting power, and the wiring I’m seeing is somewhat confusing to me.

I have a heat only system, so in my old stat the R and W were used only (there was a jumper between Rc and Rh but I don’t think that did anything…I do have a stand-alone split AC unit but it is completely separate AFAIK). Green and Blue were not attached on either end, so I took the Blue and attached it to the C terminal on the thermostat. I also attached it to the C terminal on the furnace. My stat is telling me no C wire is detected.

I’m not sure if this is related or not, but oddly the W runs to the G on the furnace. I checked my two neighbors (three unit condo building) And they have the same set up. My heat has always worked fine, so I’m not sure why this is done this way. I’m an electrician novice and first time homeowner so trying to figure it out…any tips?

Blue was too short so I used a white jumper.
[image: white jumper]

My jumper white and an existing white are here. You can also see the W wire from the stat that runs to the G, and nothing goes to the W
[image: terminals]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: I’m not 100% sure which it is (my manual has four schematics) but I believe it’s the first one (figure 11). Posted both to be safe…I guess this does show the W attaching to the G terminal which checks out. Does it explain why I wouldn’t be getting C power?

Comment: Is there not a wiring diagram posted on the boiler itself?

Comment: There is not. The only thing that is posted is a user manual about how to ignite the pilot, monthly maintenance, etc. Nothing in there about wiring.